# Convert XML to JSON, Issue with jaxb class being used with FasterXML

Tags: java, json, xml, xml-parsing

I need to convert XML to JSON at runtime, using FasterXML and generated beans from JAXB tool xjc using the source XSD.

I am using follwing code

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {


            Testing tObj=new Testing();
            ObjectMapper tester=tObj.createJaxbObjectMapper();
            CustomerOrderType data=tester.readValue(TEST_XML_STRING, CustomerOrderType.class);
            //ObjectMapper serializr=new ObjectMapper();
            //serializr.writeValue(System.out, data);


        } catch (Exception je) {
            System.out.println(je.toString());
        }
    }

    public ObjectMapper createJaxbObjectMapper()  
    {  
       final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();  
       final TypeFactory typeFactory = TypeFactory.defaultInstance();  
       final AnnotationIntrospector introspector = new JaxbAnnotationIntrospector(typeFactory);   
       // make deserializer use JAXB annotations (only)  
       mapper.getDeserializationConfig().with(introspector);  
       // make serializer use JAXB annotations (only)  
       mapper.getSerializationConfig().with(introspector);  
       return mapper;  
    }
```

But I am getting an error as follows.

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unexpected character ('<' (code 60)): expected a valid value (number, String, array, object, 'true', 'false' or 'null')
 at [Source: (String)"<ns1:orderDetail xmlns:ns1="http://www.colt.net/xml/ns/webservice/manord/v1.0"><ns7:Customer_Order_Status xmlns:ns7="http://www.colt.net/xml/ns/cbe/ord/v1.0">New</ns7:Customer_Order_Status><ns8:Order_Creation_Date xmlns:ns8="http://www.colt.net/xml/ns/cbe/ord/v1.0">2018-03-06T09:03:25</ns8:Order_Creation_Date><ns9:Opportunity_Number xmlns:ns9="http://www.colt.net/xml/ns/cbe/ord/v1.0">8798</ns9:Opportunity_Number><ns10:Order_Source xmlns:ns10="http://www.colt.net/xml/ns/cbe/ord/v1.0">eOrder Lite<"[truncated 9232 chars]; line: 1, column: 2]
```

Comment: I updated the answer with an example of conversion sequence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks that you are using [JSON-java](https://github.com/stleary/JSON-java) lib, which is extremely lightweight and does not provide a possibility to skip namespaces from parsed XML tag names.

But this can be achieved using a more advanced XML/JSON processing lib, for example, [FasterXML/Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-dataformat-xml).

### Update

To convert `String xml` to Json:

1) Use `com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat:jackson-dataformat-xml` lib dependency.

2) Conversion sequence is similar to:

```
XmlMapper xmlMapper = new XmlMapper();
MyObject myObj = xmlMapper.readValue(xml, MyObject.class);

ObjectMapper jsonMapper = new ObjectMapper();
String json = jsonMapper.writeValueAsString(myObj);

System.out.println(json);
```

Comment: that is a whole new world there. let me dive into it.

Comment: need some help, i have updated the question for FasterXML and JAXB

Comment: I tried using the above code, but there is some issue with Custom complex type. so I had to use regular jaxb api to convert the stream to POJO. I am able to make json properly with regular ObjectMapper. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

An off-the-shelf XML-to-JSON converter is never going to give you optimal output for your particular application. You generally need to apply either some preprocessing (an XML transformation using XSLT) or some post-processing of the JSON.

In this case I would suggest doing an XSLT transformation to drop the namespaces.

Comment: that was i planned to do so initially..  but after a detailed look at the Source XSD, i needed a more powerful library i will try FasterXML for now. thanks